# Recyclerview first item start margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

How do I align the first item to `tvFoo` when starting the fragment (without putting the`RecyclerView` inside another container)?

Right now, `tvFoo` is separated 16dp from the left edge and the first item from the list, only 8dp.

What I want is that the horizontal list is visible completely across the screen when scrolling (but at the beginning it is 16dp from the left).

**This is what I have**
[image]

**This is what I want**
[image]

**fragment_foo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFoo"
        style="@style/Tv.16.Black"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/foo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCount"
        style="@style/Tv.13.Gray"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvFoo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvFoo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvFoo"
        tools:text="(21)"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        style="@style/WrapContent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFoo"
        tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_foo"
        tools:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_foo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    style="@style/WrapContent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFoo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_picture_64dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Gabriel, because your question is about UI, why don't you show with pictures what you have, and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: It is related to the left border, @PriyankVadariya.

Comment: Okay, can you upload image what you exactly want? as per @Alessio comment so we can help you

Comment: Thany you, @Alessio. Done!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Add **padding** to your `RecyclerView` and Use

> `android:clipToPadding = "false"`

inside your `RecyclerView`, to disable padding while scrolling it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        style="@style/WrapContent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"     
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:clipToPadding = "false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFoo"
        tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_foo"
        tools:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Comment: It is perfect. The only one to take into account is change `android:padding="16dp"` by  `android:padding="8dp"` due that I have `android:layout_marginStart="8dp"` on items.

Comment: I always forget the `clipToPadding`... :-D